# How can I disable HTTP/2 in Traefik

Tags: http2, traefik

Can I disable HTTP/2 in Traefik and just use HTTP/1.1?

*reads your mind*

Because I'm facing a showstopper bug of doom where *one* Chrome or Chromium request will stall for over 59 seconds (but not quite a minute!) before closing the HTTP/2 session and trying to fetch a resource again (unless it is requested via requireJS, which will cancel the thing after umpteen seconds). The problem does not happen if we start Chrome or Chromium with the `--disable-http2` argument. It also does not happen in the same application hosted in a different (testing) environment that does not support HTTP/2 (using a NodeJS-based proxy specifically).

There are other variables at play. I'm not convinced that disabling HTTP/2 will workaround the problem, but telling Traefik to pretend that it can only do HTTP/1.1 seems like an easy thing to try.

Comment: Question on trying to enable HTTP/2 in the NodeJS proxy for the same reason I want to disable it in Traefik: github.com/AveVlad/gulp-connect/issues/255

Just deleted a comment linking to the Chromium issue that is now private.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't without altering source code.

Comment: There's a PR open for this now https://github.com/traefik/traefik/pull/7645